# Working with temporary files in ArcObjects using Geodatabases?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, esri-geodatabase

My current add-ons rely on shapefiles for working with temporary files. For example, if I run a spatial analyst tool, I create a new shapefile to store the output geometry. ArcGIS stores all temporary files in a default GDB. Can someone point me in the direction of some .NET code or resources that would help me to structure my temporary file handling in the same way? It would be nice to have everything in one GDB that could be cleared, rather than in a folder containing many shapefiles and rasters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might try using a [scratch workspace](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000004t8000000) or an [inmemoryworkspace](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/dotnet/fde31db0-af15-409f-81b5-75c23d4a762e.htm#CreateInMemory).

Comment: Follow-up on this.  I'd recommend trying InMemoryWorkspace first so you can avoid writing to disk.  If that doesn't meet your needs (it doesn't support everything) then use FileGDBScratchWorkspaceFactory.  There is really no need to use ScratchWorkspaceFactory anymore (it is based on a personal GDB and has all the limitations of personal GDBs with file size etc.)

Comment: @Craig Williams; actually its based on the fGDB not Personal or MDB file; and it is set to the default 4GB max-size. I found this to be problematic with large jobs where I needed to write out more than that; instead of the default of no-size-limit to keep expanding it would crash my process. This is by design of ESRI to keep a run-a-way process from eating all your disk and then crashing your machine. It really should be optional.

Comment: Both of these are actually very useful for me (inmemory and GDBscratch). Thanks for the insight @Craig.

Comment: @Craig I think inmemoryworkspaces will become even more useful when arcgis server is available for 64 bit.  However, to truly leverage that, a new option is needed when creating an msd file: an option that lets you specify that a layer's featureclass should be cached into memory when the map service starts up.  This should improve performance.

Comment: @D.E.Wright ScratchWorkspaceFactory is based on Access.  FileGDBScratchWorkspaceFactory is based on FileGDB.  This is a very important distinction. InMemoryWorkspace is different from personal or FileGDB.

Comment: @Kirk Caching data in memory would greatly bloat the footprint of the service.

Comment: @Craig That's why it would be an option.  Suppose I have a mapservice serving just one layer in a filegdb that's 18GB.  If I buy 24 GB of RAM, I should still have plenty left over for other processes.  Responding to an identify request using an inmemory featureclass should be a lot faster than hitting the file.  This could be validated by writing an SOE that caches the same featureclass in memory as the mapservice at startup, and has an Identify operation exposed.  Then just compare which is faster, the Identify on the mapservice, or the Identify method on the SOE.

Comment: I understand what you are sating, but you'd only have RAM for one server instance in this case.

Comment: I think the InMemory workspace could be suplanted in the 64bit realm with the use of a appropriate RAMDISK over even SSD storage. If your working space for the servics is say 20GB, you could buy an additional 36GB Storage, setup that as a logical RAMDISK; and have your data for your service reside there. Even the option of storing your ScratchWorkspaces there would be a option then. There are good drivers to support this; that can save the state to a image to restore at reboot.

Comment: If memory serves me right, the InMemoryWorkspace will switch internally to a ScratchWorkspace once it hits a threshold of certain amount of features and then rearrange its internal references to make it transparent. So you are then really interacting with a ScratchWorkspace, you just do not know it. I don't remember if I added code for that or not, but I think I did... or maybe it was the ArcGIS Server folks when they were implementing disconnected editing, but I *think* that is how it works.

Comment: @RagiYaserBurhum That certainly makes D.E.Wright's RAMDISK with scratchworkspace more appealing.  Thanks to both of you for replying.